# Knowledge of universe according to various vedic texts

Tags: universe, knowledge, vedic

I wanted to know about various things and vedic books give knowledge of cosmos and universe
I have done research and found out some materials like
1.Richard thomson Mysterious of the sacred Universe:the cosmology of bhagavat purana
2.vedic rashmi theory
3.some  articles
{All the above give some insight but i wanted to know of some more on vedic universe knowledge }
Please help me